# Can I change a file/folder's index number within its parent?

Tags: windows-10, sorting

I just learned that files and folders have index numbers that are given to them when they are created inside of their parent folder or drive.  These numbers seem to be based on the order in which the items are created.  Is there any way to modify these index numbers without moving the items out of the their parent and putting them back in the desired order?

Explanation: I put music on a USB drive to play in my car.  No matter how I name or tag the files, the car seems to have its own way of sorting the items.  I finally figured out that it uses the items' "index" numbers.  As of now, the only way I know to sort the items the way I want is to remove them from the USB drive and then put them back in a particular order.  It would be much easier if I could just change the index without moving the files.  I hope this is possible.

I'm using Windows 10x64.

Comment: I don't think there would be any "index number", your car just plays the music in the physical order as they're on the drive.  So your only option is to copy them in the order you want to listen them.